# Is it possible to rate a page generated with Views using the fivestar module?

Tags: views, rating

[Fivestar](http://drupal.org/project/fivestar) works well with nodes, but is it possible to rate a page generated by [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views)? I can add the widget in a template, but how do I save the results? In the project description page of fivestar, it states that in Drupal 7 you can use it on any entity, but I don't think a Views page is an entity, is it? I found an [old issue](http://drupal.org/node/633016) on the issue queue about this, but it was never updated once the new API was written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I normally use a "hidden" node to accomplish this.  Typically, I will make a content type called something like  "internal use".  Then, I will make a panel page that contains an "inernal use node and my view.  The node-ish actions then get associate with this node.

Comment: I guess this works, instead of using a panel though, I'll just use a node template that embeds the view and also prints the fivestar widget only. Thanks! I'll leave this open to see if I get more answers, but I'll award the answer to you if no one comes up with anything better.